# eventhandler (example from JavaScript & JQuery by Jon Duckett)

Tags: javascript, blur, addeventlistener

```
function checkUsername() {
        var elMsg= document.getElementById("feedback");
        if (elUsername.value.length < 5) {
                elMsg.textContent= ' Test' ;
        }
        else {
                elMsg.textContent= 'Test2';

        }
}
var elUsername = document.getElementById('username');
elUsername.blur = checkUsername;
```

The function is working, but not the call. I can call it from html (with the second last line, then in the function) 
What am I doing wrong ? 
Probably something stupid, but I have been at it all day.

Also tried: `elUsername.addEventListener('blur', checkUsername, false);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

js
define `var` before
and `blur` missing `on`

```js
    var elUsername = document.getElementById('username');
    var elMsg= document.getElementById("feedback");
    function checkUsername() {
          if (elUsername.value.length < 5) {
               elMsg.textContent= ' Test' ;
          } else {
               elMsg.textContent= 'Test2';
          }
    }
    elUsername.onblur = checkUsername;
    //elUsername.addEventListener('blur', checkUsername, false);
```

```html
<input id="username" value="123456">
<div id="feedback"></div>
```

Comment: The code snippet work, but it don't work on any of my browsers, when I copy and paste it. I define my script with <script></script>. Can't even get the HTML onblur call to work, it works when I define my var inside the function. My bad about the onblur, been tossing it around. Thank you for your replay.

Comment: I just copied and pasted.Putting the script in <script></script>. My Firefox has NoScript, but I also tried Chrome,Opera and another laptop with IE.

Comment: first => `html`, after => `<script>` : => `<input id="username" value="123456"><div id="feedback"></div><script> /*some code*/ </script>`